# Local Login/Registration Android Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, authentication

I'm trying to develop a local registration procedure in my app, so the user will be able to register locally, and login with his personal user and password.

Can someone give me a simple example how can i accomplish this? Meaning how do i store the local username and password input in registration, and later login with this data?

For example this will be my Login and Registarion html pages:

```
<body onload="init()">

<div id="loginPage" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Registration/Login Demo</h1>
    </div>

     <div data-role="content">    

         <form id="loginForm">
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
             <label for="username">Username:</label>
             <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""     placeholder="Username" />
         </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="password">Re-enter Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
    </form>

</div>
```

How do i construct my js file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storage API of Cordova,which *Provides access to the devices storage options* as you like to keep process locally,
Two options you can use for achieving this goal; one is database and the other one is local storage.         [Look here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) for storage API docs